# Karhunen-Loeve expansion for random elements in a Hilbert space

Tags: stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces

I've been trying to understand how the Karhunen-Loeve expansion works in general Hilbert spaces.

If we for example consider a random element $X$ in the space $\mathbb{L}^2([a,b])$ we have

$X_t= \sum_k Z_ke_k(t)$
with
$ Z_k= \int_a^b X_te_k(t) \mathrm{d}t$,

where we can verify that the scores are uncorrelated by exchanging the expected value with the integrals.

Can anyone explain to me how this works when the random elements are in some general (separable) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$? How does the KL-expansion look here? Furhter, if I want to prove that the scores $Z_i,Z_j$ are uncorrelated i got

$\mathbb{E} [\langle X,e_i \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}  \langle X,e_j \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}]  $

and i don't really know how to deal with this.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Pretty much the same, $Z_{k}:=\langle X_{t}, e_{k}\rangle$ with an ONB $\lbrace e_{k}\rbrace $ in $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to deal with $\mathbb{E}[Z_i Z_j]$? In the $\mathbb{L}^2$ case one can interchange the integrals due to Fubini. Is there any analogue here?